# Automatic outlier detection in R

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, multiple-regression, outliers, sparse

Our model processes millions of multivariate observations; manual outlier detection is impractical. I am looking for a method of automatic outlier detection.

I have been trying to use R package `mvoutliers`, especially function `pcout`, and get the error

> More than 50% equal values in one or more variables!

The problem is that our data is quite sparse and many variables include *More than 50% equal values*.

1. Is there any way around (some data preprocessing) that would still allow me to use `pcout`?
2. Is there another recommended R package/function/method for automatic outlier detection?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the data after outlier detection? If your plan is to remove outliers, maybe there is a [robust method](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Robust.html) you could use intead.

Comment: Have you tried lofactor() function from DMwR package?

Comment: I am planning, among others, to perform regression analysis; we use OLS regression as of business constraints, robust regression is out of question here; but we can use robust outlier detection

Comment: Can you then do outlier detection post-analysis? That is, look for high leverage points, etc. in the model you fit? 

Of course, you can also do one-dimensional outlier detection on each of your variables before the regression.

Comment: @PeterFlom - this is impractical because the regression coefficients would be skewed. Univariate detection is not so effective in our dataset.

Comment: @MiroslavSabo - lofactor() looks promising should do some more reading about it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have time right now for a longer answer, but there are statistics that look at what leaving each point out of the data set would do to the model. Of course, this finds only one outlier at a time, but it's a start

Comment: @Herbert, I had the same problems with mvoutliers. Then I tried lofactor() and everything works. There may be only computational problems since your dataset is very large.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, the term outliers doesn't make sense without the context of the application. That is, if you want to exclude data points from your data set, you should be able to give reasons why this or that data point is removed. These reasons may suggest appropriate filtering rules.

Therefore I think that something like the "recommended R package/function/method for automatic outlier detection" cannot exist in general, it can exist only for particular types of data/applications.

Answer (score 5):

An outlier is only an outlier with respect to some model. What's hugely discrepant under one set of assumptions is just an ordinary point under another, something to be expected in the ordinary course of events.

If your data are often of a particular form, it might help to think about what you mean by 'outlier' for that kind of distributional situation, and tailor your automated procedure to deal with the situation you're in, rather than try to squeeze it into something it's not suited to.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a very samll random number to your data.

Comment: Im not sure whether the OP wants to change the existing data. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: A less intrusive tweak would be adding to only those variables with this problem?